# Want my program to check if numbers in a list are in increasing order

Tags: python

```py
Truth = False

list = [1, 2, 3, 6, 4]
for i in range(0,3):
    if list[i] < list[i +1]:
        Truth = True
    else :
        Truth = False
if Truth == True:
    print('nums increase ')
else:
    print('not increasing')
```

Comment: Please don't use `list` as a variable name as you're overriding the Python keyword of the same name. If your list is called `a` you can just check `if a == sorted(a)`.

Comment: You current code effectively compares only the last two elements. All the others are irrelevant as `Truth` is reset on every iteration.

Comment: @DavidBuck It's not a keyword.

Comment: While @KellyBundy is correct that technically `list` is a rather important class name rather than a reserved keyword, the advice remains valid.  "Don't use `list` as a variable name` :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `all()` function to check this

```
lst = [ ... ]
is_sorted = all(lst[x] < lst[x + 1] for x in range(len(lst) - 1))
```

Comment: That is a good approach as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather do something a little bit different: you can start with Truth=true, than whenever you find an element like list[i] > list[i+1], then you make Truth=false and stop the iteration

Comment: This is a sound answer. If you add some code demonstrating how to do this, I will remove what is essentially this as the current 3rd part of my answer.

Comment: `Var = [0, 1, 2]

def Is_Order_Foo(list):
    for i in range(0,len(list) - 1 ):
        if list[i] > list[i +1]:
            return print('nums not increasing')
    return print('nums increase')

Is_Order_Foo(Var)`

You can do something like this: you can avoid to think the length of the list while you are writing the code and then assume that when you start the list is in order but whenever there's a number in the wrong position you stop check all the list. Maybe you do also some tricks with comprehension list and do all the stuff in just one line, but I did a more C like approach

Answer (score 0):

Your logic looks fine. Not rewriting it. just changing the Truth=1 and Truth=Truth*1 or 0

```
Truth = 1

list = [1, 2, 3, 6, 4]
for i in range(len(list)-1):
    if list[i] < list[i +1]:
        Truth = Truth*1
    else :
        Truth = Truth*0
        break
if Truth == 1:
    print('nums increase ')
else:
    print('not increasing')
```

Comment: Ah yes, put a break in the else after the Truth = Truth*0

Comment: It would be better to invert the condition and just remove the "else". There is no reason to multiply 1 by 1.